# Number of Days into Date Android

Tags: java, android, string, date, days

Sir I have a date like "08-25-2013" as a string, I got the number of days from this string date, now I add few number days in it like  long days=days+250; now the question is how can I get the date like "05-02-2014" as a string. Please answer me as soon as possible please thanks in advance respected sir.
Qustions: number of days convert to the date.

Comment: try the code i have posted its simple and working fine

Comment: thanks  Gaurav Pandey

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date dateparsed = sdf.parse("29-08-2013");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dateparsed); 
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 250); // Adding n number of days 
        String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: thank Gaurav Pandey for answering my question its also a valid answer and short